# How to show recorded value in Edit Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a master detail working, but when I go to the edit form the select field isn't shown as recorded in the database, it's showing the first `option_for_select`:

```
<div class='fields'>
  <div class='span-24 last'>
    <div class='span-11'>
      <%= f.select :ordem, options_for_select([["0", 0], ["1", 1], ["2", 2], ["3", 3], ["4", 4], ["5", 5]]) %>
    </div>
    <div class='span-8'><%= f.text_field :opcao %></div>

    <div class='last'>
      <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>  
      <%= link_to_function '(X)', "remove_fields(this)" %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So what do I have to do to show the recorded content for this select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add a `:selected` option containing the id of the option to select:

```
f.select :ordem, [["0", 0], ["1", 1]], {:selected => '1'}
```

Comment: @Fábio Coelho, please see the updated response. The reason why it didn't worked is that you don't need to use `options_for_select` for the `select` form helper. You need that only when using `select_tag` instead